# How to render and import an asp.net page into another asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I have a ASP.NET page. I have another asp.net page, that i would like to render and import it's rendered results into my asp.net page. I don't want to use  or use AJAX request as that would cause my visitors to make an unnecessary HTTP request and decrease performance.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the other page to a usercontrol, and consume it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but take a look at the [Execute(String, TextWriter, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.execute.aspx) method of the HttpServerUtility class:

```
Server.Execute("OtherPage.aspx", Response.Output, true);
```

Comment: Now that I've got you motivated, go read through the MSDN documentation on the HttpServerUtility, HttpRequest, HttpResponse and HttpContext objects. You won't catch all the features all at once, but we depend on them so much, that it's good to scan the documentation from time to time, at least a couple of times a year. I've never used this call, but I knew it was there, and this is how I knew.

Answer (score 0):

Override the calling page's Render method to call the target page's Render method and insert the contents in the rendered output..

Comment: How about page life cycle of the other page?